# text not getting vertically centered

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, responsive

I am trying to create clickable tiles (box shaped) on dashboard.

**Problem 1:** I tried using flexbox but vertical alignment didnt work for me. so I tried using padding-top. What I am looking for is that the tiles should have vertically centered icons and text which should also be maintained responsively (Bootstrap Used).

```
div.wrapper{
    height:150px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top:30%;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center
}
```

Using ***padding-top*** doesnot work responsively. On decreasing the screen width, text and icon comes out of the tile. Using ***line-height*** equal to box height makes multiline text go way out of the tile.

**Problem 2:** for making full tile clickable, I tried using display:block on my anchor tag when it was inside the **div**

```
<div class="col-md-2 button-col">
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
    <br><br>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">Manage Items</a>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
a.mybutton{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    display: block;
}
```

but full tile didnot become clickable. So I placed anchor tag outside the div.

Here is my present layout:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 button-col">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                <br><br>
                Click for Production Calculation Chart
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 button-col">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                <br><br>
                Production Calculation Chart
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 button-col">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                <br><br>
                Tile Number 3
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 button-col">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                <br><br>
                This is Tile 4
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 button-col">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                <br><br>
                Tile 5
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 button-col">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                <br><br>
                Tile 6 Text
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
   <!-- And Many More Tiles Will Come and make more rows -->
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my current css:

```
div.button-col{
    padding:2rem;
}
div.wrapper{
    height:150px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center
}
div.wrapper:hover{
    background-color:blue;
    cursor: pointer
}
div.wrapper i.fa{
    color:#438EB9;
}
div.wrapper:hover i.fa {
    color:white;
} 
a.mybutton{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;
}
a.mybutton:hover
{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally a solution that worked perfect for me. ***Please suggest if this is the best solution? or we can do something better***

```
.button-col{
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px; /* for demo only */
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
        .centeralign{                
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .contentouter{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        div.button-col:hover, div.button-col:hover a{
            background-color:blue;
            color:white;
        }
        .icon{
            margin-top:30px;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        .content
        {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
        }
        .contentinner{                
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        a.my-button
        {
            font-weight:bold;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col col-sm-2 button-wrapper">
                <a href="my_url" class="my-button">
                    <div class="button-col">
                        <div class="centeralign">
                            <div class="contentouter">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="contentinner">
                                        Items
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-2 button-wrapper">
                <a href="my_url" class="my-button">
                    <div class="button-col">
                        <div class="centeralign">
                            <div class="contentouter">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="contentinner">
                                        Click for Production Calculation Chart
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to **Problem 1**:
Try setting the style to the link 'a' element and removing manual positioning and user `vertical-align` property instead:

```
div.wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper a{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've also removed the `<br>` from the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2 button-col">
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>

    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>listitems" class="mybutton">Manage Items</a>
</div>
</div>
```

If you still want a `<i>` and `<a>` each to set in their own lines then wrap `<i>` with `<div>` and it should get vertically and horizontally centred.

Notice that a proper display type like `inline-block` is required to get vertical center working.

See it in action https://jsfiddle.net/74wg2za6/

Answer to **Problem 2**
To get the whole tile clickable simply wrap your whole wrapper div with `<a>` instead of making text "Manage Items" only clickable, see it here

https://jsfiddle.net/kr45qoa1/

I just leveraged the `<a>` tag up to wrap all `<div>`, `<i>` and text.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: As I said, I need to have a tile (a square box) which will have a font awesome icon and then the tile text in next line. For this purpose I used break tags that you have removed. Secondaly, if I increase the height of .wrapper (because I want to look it somewhat like a box), The text just stays aligned on top, not vertically aligned. Please check: https://jsfiddle.net/xLw29jro/

Comment: And the solution that you have suggested, I have already written that in my problem description. Please check My Current Layout section. I wanted to know if it was possible to be done by keeping anchor inside the .wrapper

Comment: @ITSagar Alright, as I mentioned above, you don't need the height as it will break the vertical centring .. use paddings instead.

Comment: @ITSagar for the icon font, it was also suggested to use div instead of br and will give the result you want.

Comment: but I have mentioned in the problem description that I used padding:30% which didnot work. I need to keep the height of tile as 150px, then I need centering of text, that too responsively

Comment: @ITSagar aha so 150px height is required, can't you use padding up and bottom to achieve same height ? like this: https://jsfiddle.net/v93c1dmn/

Comment: but being col-md-2, a row will have 6 tiles. and text length may vary in each tile. Then padding will behave badly. I thought you will understand col-md-2 automatically. However for more clearity, I have updated problem description code with more columns.

Comment: I see, I will setup an example and experiment with a solution that matches your needs, you will be using bootstrap right?

Comment: yes, bootstrap is used (I mentioned responsiveness too in description) :)

Comment: 150px is not specifically required, just trying to make it look like a bit square box, you may change it to a better value if we get better results

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src='js/fontawesome-all.min.js'></script>

<style>

    div.button-col{
        height:150px;
        line-height: 150px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 20px auto;
        text-align:center;
    }

    a.mybutton{
        width: 90%;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        border:1px solid black;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    a.mybutton:hover {
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 button-col">
            <a href="my_url" class="mybutton">
                <i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
                <br><br>
                Click for Production Calculation Chart
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought you will understand col-md-2 automatically. However for more clearity, I have updated problem description code with more columns. Length of text may vary in each tile.